# How can I remove an all-zero column from a 3D array without reducing the dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to remove an all-zero column from a 3D array using numpy while maintaining the number of dimensions. I don't want to use trim either as the columns might not be at the edges of the array.

[Intended functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9kX8.png)

I tried using `~np.all` but that seems to strip away one of the dimensions:

```
import numpy as np

vals = [1,0,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
array = np.reshape(vals, (2,2,3))
```

array:

```
[[[ 1  0  3]
  [ 4  0  6]]

 [[ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]]
```

This is what I want to see:

```
[[[ 1  3]
  [ 4  6]]

 [[ 7  9]
  [10 12]]]
```

Comment: 1) How is that operation maintaining the dimensions? The example array went from 2x2x2 to 2x1x2. 2) Do not use `list` as a variable name since it is a built-in Python keyword.

Comment: @jared new_array.shape gives (3,2). Thanks, good point R.E list

Comment: I was referring to the shape of the array in the intended functionality image.

Comment: @jared I've replaced the image to make it a bit clearer and also tidied up the code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this up into multiple steps.

1. Use the `astype` method to convert the array to booleans. Columns of all `False` are 0s.
2. Use NOT on the array to convert columns of 0s from `False` to `True`.
3. Use `all` on axis 1 to perform a logical AND, which checks if a column is all 0s.
4. Use `any` on axis 0 to perform a logical OR, which collapses the result to get `True` or `False` values for each column in the array.
5. Use the NOT version of the result to index the last axis of the array to only get the columns that don't have the 0.

With labeled steps:

```py
import numpy as np

vals = [1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
array = np.reshape(vals, (2, 2, 3))
step1 = array.astype(bool)
step2 = ~step1
step3 = step2.all(1)
step4 = step3.any(0)
step5 = array[..., ~step4]
```

All together:

```py
vals = [1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
array = np.reshape(vals, (2, 2, 3))
res = array[..., ~(~array.astype(bool)).all(1).any(0)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[[[ 1  3]
  [ 4  6]]

 [[ 7  9]
  [10 12]]]
```